# Is Folksonomy and Enterprise Keyword the same thing?

Tags: managed-metadata, enterprise-keywords

I have been asked to add folksonomy to a document library.  How would i achieve this?

Would i add a 'Enterprise Keywords' column to the document library or can the user enter folksonomy using the 'Tag' button on the ribbon?

How is folksonomy implemented? i understand and have taxonomy working fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
http://sharepointams.com/taxonomy-and-folksonomy/

Taxonomy is the formal, hierarchical structure of tags which are usually managed by staff.  Folksonomy is similar to taxonomy, but users create the tags.  Members, Volunteers, Donors, Board Members, Chapter Leaders, Registered Users, or anyone you allow can add tags to your folksonomy.  SharePoint offers both, and both are very important.
In SharePoint 2010, Terms are your taxonomy, and Keywords are your folksonomy.
Personalization can also be achieved using SharePoint Audiences.  Audiences are logical groups of users that you define with similar attributes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally a taxonomy is a closed term set which means that users cannot add new terms.

A folksonomy is an open term set meaning users can add new terms.

You could add the standard Enterprise Keywords which is an open terms set or you could use your own custom term set and check the setting to make it open.